# How to echo an str_replace only if array exists in results

Tags: php, foreach, echo, str-replace

I'm very amateur when it comes to PHP, so hopefully this makes sense.  I have the following foreach loop that fetches all of the "credits" that are linked to a music artist using that artist's id (mixer, producer, arranger, composer, etc).  I want to be able to replace the different credit names with something more "list friendly."  The attempt below works but it only loops until it hits a credit that is not linked to the artist, then it stops.

```
<?php function getSkills($id)
{
    $query = "SELECT c2a.credit_id, cr.credit_name
FROM  `Credit_To_Artist` AS c2a
INNER JOIN  `Credits` AS cr ON cr.credit_id = c2a.credit_id
INNER JOIN  `Artist` AS a ON a.artist_id = c2a.artist_id
WHERE c2a.artist_id = $id
GROUP BY c2a.credit_id
ORDER BY cr.credit_name";

    $res = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $skills[] = $row;
    }

    return $skills;

}
?>

<?php foreach (getSkills($id) as $skill): ?>

    <?php echo str_replace(
            array('arranger','mixer','producer','composer','engineer','mixer','recorder','vocalist','writer'),
            array('song arrangement','audio mixing','music production','music/vocal recording','song writing','singing/performance'),
            $skill['credit_name']); ?><br />

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How do I go about adding a if statement into the code so that it only replaces the "array" that is in the result?

Comment: You're not escaping the output properly (assuming you're building an HTML response); besides that, there's nothing inherently wrong with the code itself ... does `getSkills($id)` return the right amount of data?

Comment: can you add the data in `$skill['credit_name']`? Will make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've updated my question with the getSkills function hopefully it makes it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's replies, I fiddled with the suggestions posted and realized that I hadn't specified enough of the original `credit_name`'s in the first array to match the second one.  And it also must be a string because `if(is_string)` works and `if(is_array)` doesn't.  (As I said, still very green to all of this!)

```
<?php foreach (getSkills($id) as $skill): ?>

    <?php if(is_string($skill['credit_name'])) {
    echo str_replace(
            array('arranger','mixer','producer','composer','engineer','recorder','vocalist','writer'),
            array('song arrangement','audio mixing','music production','song composition','music engineering','music/vocal recording','singing/performance','song writing'),
            $skill['credit_name']);
    echo "<br />";
    } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: So, does this solve your problem? If so, please accept your own answer

Comment: Yes it does, I tried but it told me I have to wait to accept it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Add a check if `$skill['credit_name']` is an array or not -

```
if(is_array($skill['credit_name'])) {
    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) function along with [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) as

```
if(is_array($skill['credit_name']) && count($skill['credit_name']) > 0){
    echo str_replace(array('arranger','mixer','producer','composer','engineer','mixer','recorder','vocalist','writer'), array('song arrangement','audio mixing','music production','music/vocal recording','song writing','singing/performance'), $skill['credit_name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything beside evaluating skills inside this `foreach()`, you can put the whole block outside like below assuming `$skill['credit_name']` is string,

```
<?php if(is_array(getSkills($id)): ?>
<?php foreach (getSkills($id) as $skill): ?>
<?php if(is_string($skill['credit_name']) && $skill['credit_name']!=''): ?>


<?php echo str_replace(
        array('arranger','mixer','producer','composer','engineer','mixer','recorder','vocalist','writer'),
        array('song arrangement','audio mixing','music production','music/vocal recording','song writing','singing/performance'),
        $skill['credit_name']); ?><br />

<?php endif?>
<?php endforeach?>
<?php endif?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing,

```
$result = getSkills($id);

$search = array('arranger','mixer','producer','composer','engineer','mixer','recorder','vocalist','writer');
$replace = array('song arrangement','audio mixing','music production','music/vocal recording','song writing','singing/performance');

foreach($result as &$v)
{
    $v['credit_name'] = str_replace($search,$replace,$v['credit_name']);
}
```

Now `$result` contains replaced strings.